# perform preg match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

How to perform a `preg_match` this

```
 $needle = '"pid": "20"';
 $haystack = '"pid": "1"' . '"pid": "12"' . '"pid": "20"' . '"pid": "14"';
```

and by the way the needle numeric value is not static
i am novice at `preg_match`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[0-9]+  // Matches 1 or more numbers from 0 to 9
```

This is *exactly* what you asked for, but if you provide what your expected output is or how you receive your haystack, there may be a better suited solution than regular expressions.

```
$needle   = '/"pid": "[0-9]+"/';
$haystack = '"pid": "1"' . '"pid": "12"' . '"pid": "20"' . '"pid": "14"';

preg_match_all($needle,$haystack,$matches);
```

**`$matches` Output**

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "pid": "1"
            [1] => "pid": "12"
            [2] => "pid": "20"
            [3] => "pid": "14"
        )

)
```

To learn more about regular expressions, [check out this basic syntax reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Better to match 0 or spaces in the pid string so use your regex like this:

```
$needle = '/"pid"\s*:\s*"\d+"/';
```